# PyCharm not Indenting After Newline on Extremely Specific File

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I'm experiencing an infuriating issue in PyCharm. For some reason, within a specific file named "DataStorage.py", when I press the "Enter" key after a function or class declaration, it does not auto-indent as it usually would. Instead, it just moves the cursor to a new line with a single space. Additionally, the "Tab" key, which typically indents code, is now only producing spaces. This behavior is confined to this SPECIFIC file. If I copy all the code in that file into a new .py file, the issue DOES NOT occur, UNLESS I try to start using that file in other places across my code, and then it suddenly starts happening again.

Because I was asked to further clarify, here's a detailed breakdown of the issue:

-I have a file called "DataStorage.py" in a large PyCharm project I'm working on.

-For this specific file, and only for this specific file, I am unable to create tab characters anymore.

-If I press the "tab" key, it simply creates a space instead of a tab.

-If PyCharm tries to automatically create a tab, for instance after I declare a function and hit "enter" to go to the next line, it tries to automatically tab for me but instead creates a single space.

-My tabs are currently set as "4 spaces" in the Pycharm settings. I have set this to every conceivable option and not once did it even effect the tabbing done in DataStorage.py

=This only occurs in this one SPECIFIC file. All other files, I can create tabs (4 spaces) without any issues.

---

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

-Checked the Editor > Code Style > Python settings to ensure the correct indentation settings.
-Restarted PyCharm.
-Completely reinstalled PyCharm.
-Completely changed PyCharm versions
-Deleted and recloned the entire project from Github
-Reset all Pycharm settings, both on a project level and global level
-Verified that the issue is not present in other IDEs with the same file.
-Deleting the actual contents of DataStorage.py and trying it with a single function - still occurs

I just don't get what's happening. This issue randomly started happening while I was in the middle of coding this file. I think it MIGHT have occurred when I accidentally opened the search everywhere menu by double-tapping shift, but I've checked literally every single setting there and nothing's helped. Maybe it was a different menu that popped up? I closed it so fast when it happened that I didn't get a good look.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm completely out of ideas and so is ChatGPT. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.